# How can I stop a former FB friend showing in my contacts list in Facebook.com

Tags: facebook

The right-hand side of Facebook.com shows a Contacts list, and each contact's current online status. I have ended a difficult friendship with someone but they still show in this list.

I have already:

- deleted our FB chat
- stopped being FB friends
- in the FB *app* found a "remove contact" option

None of these make any difference, in the web-browser they are still listed and it's rather hard seem them, popping up online, etc. I know I can hide the entire Contacts panel but I don't want to do this.
I do notice that looking at their profile they still show as starred/favourites - but they are not in this list anymore so I can't turn that off.

I don't really want to totally block this person, just not be constantly reminded that they are online. I am not even certain that blocking them *would* remove them from this list?